# Finding two person id which are there in both column

Tags: mysql

Below is what I have

```
+++++++++++++++++
+id1    +   id2 +
+++++++++++++++++
+  1    +    2  +
+  2    +    1  +
+  1    +    3  +
+  3    +    2  +
+  4    +    5  +
+  5    +    4  +
+++++++++++++++++
```

What I want to find is the id of two person which are in both column.

Below is what I will have

```
+++++++++++++++++
+id1    +   id2 +
+++++++++++++++++
+  1    +    2  +
+  2    +    1  +
+  4    +    5  +
+  5    +    4  +
+++++++++++++++++
```

### OR

```
+++++++++++++++++
+id1    +   id2 +
+++++++++++++++++
+  1    +    2  +
+  4    +    5  +
+++++++++++++++++
```

### OR

```
+++++++++++++++++
+id1    +   id2 +
+++++++++++++++++
+  2    +    1  +
+  5    +    4  +
+++++++++++++++++
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

### [Here is testing data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80feb)

Comment: Have you tried anything? An `INNER JOIN` with the same table might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
    mytable1.id1, mytable1.id2
FROM
    myTable mytable1,
    myTable mytable2
WHERE
    mytable1.id1 = mytable2.id2
    AND
    mytable2.id1 = mytable1.id2
ORDER BY
    mytable1.id1
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80feb/2)

Comment: Well, as I say, I think I understand the title of the question, but your three required resultsets are confusing. Presumably only one resultset can come out of this?

Comment: Earlier you have OR... I just updated it to AND and it worked && I dont need DISTINCT tooo

Answer (score 0):

The basic id list is this:

```
select distinct t1.id1
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2;
```

If you want *rows*:

```
select distinct t1.*
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2;
```

If you want any 2 rows:

```
select distinct t1.*
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2
limit 2;
```

Comment: none of your query is giving me desired result. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80feb/4)

Comment: @FahimParkar - it's generally a good idea to take helpful answers and modify them to your needs - only you know _exactly_ what you want. I'd venture to say it's not quite in the spirit of StackOverflow to downvote people who are trying to help you, especially if they have good rep.